# Null pointer Exception in ContextWrapper

Tags: android

I am using a ListActivity and this throws Null Pointer Exception

```
private ContextWrapper ctx;
return ctx.getContentResolver().query(
                Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {
                    Data.DATA1
                },
                Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=" + this.getId() + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "= '" + mimetype
                        + "'", null, null);
```

ctx is not initialized , what should be initialized to ?

Answer (score 0):

Your ListActivity IS a ContextWrapper (see the Javadoc at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) so it does not need to instantiate one. Instead, just call the getContentResolver() on the ListActivity itself:

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
    ...
    return getContentResolver().query(
            Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {
                Data.DATA1
            },
            Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=" + this.getId() + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "= '" + mimetype
                    + "'", null, null);
```